# How to use buffer allocation and mapping memory mechanism iin OpenCL?

Tags: c++, c, performance, memory-management, opencl

I am a little confused as to whether my code using OpenCL mapped buffers are correct.

I've understood that buffer/map specific operations is the most efficient way to use mapped(zero-copy) memory mechanism with GPU in OpenCL environment.

I don't understand why `res_nb` is not initializing to 0 at each iteration.
At each iteration `res_nb` is multiplied by 2

I am aware I should do error checking and so forth.

**OpenCL code**

```
__kernel void test(
    __global uint* res_nb_g,
)
{
    // atomicAdd will return the value which was stored at "res_nb_g" before "1" was added.
    int i = atomic_add(res_nb_g, 1);
}
```

**C code**

```
cl_uint res_nb = 0;

cl_mem res_nb_g = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_uint), &res_nb, &clStatus);

clSetKernelArg(test_kernel, 0, sizeof(res_nb_g), &res_nb_g);

for (int run = 0; run < 10; run++) {
    res_nb = *((cl_uint *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(clqueue, res_nb_g, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, sizeof(cl_uint), 0, NULL, NULL, NULL));
    res_nb = 0;
    clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(clqueue, res_nb_g, &res_nb, 0, NULL, NULL);

    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(clqueue, test_kernel, 1, NULL, &g_work_size, &l_work_size, 0, NULL, NULL);

    clFinish(clqueue);

    res_nb = *((cl_uint *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(clqueue, res_nb_g, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(cl_uint), 0, NULL, NULL, &clStatus));
}
```

**Edit with my solution :**

```
    cl_uint *res_nb = 0;
    cl_mem res_nb_g = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_uint), NULL, &clStatus);
    clCheckError(clStatus);

    clStatus = clSetKernelArg(test_kernel, 0, sizeof(res_nb_g), &res_nb_g);
    clCheckError(clStatus);

    for (cl_uint run = 0; run < nbruns; run++) {
        res_nb = (cl_uint *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(clqueue, res_nb_g, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, sizeof(cl_uint), 0, NULL, NULL, &clStatus);
        clCheckError(clStatus);
        *res_nb = 0;
        clStatus = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(clqueue, res_nb_g, res_nb, 0, NULL, NULL);
        clCheckError(clStatus);

        clStatus = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(clqueue, test_kernel, 1, NULL, &g_work_size, &l_work_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
        clCheckError(clStatus);

        clFinish(clqueue); // Not necessary

        res_nb = (cl_uint *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(clqueue, res_nb_g, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(cl_uint), 0, NULL, NULL, &clStatus);
        clCheckError(clStatus);
        // Edit: remark @ Andrew Savonichev
        clStatus = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(clqueue, res_nb_g, res_nb, 0, NULL, NULL);
        clCheckError(clStatus);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me explain what `clEnqueueMapBuffer` does: it maps a device
buffer into host address space and returns a pointer to this mapped
memory. Exactly this pointer must be passed to `clEnqueueUnmapMemObject` in
order to commit the changes back to a device buffer.

`res_nb = *((cl_uint *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(clqueue, res_nb_g, [...]);`

On this line you immediately dereference a pointer and assign a value to a local
variable. Original pointer returned by `clEnqueueMapBuffer` is lost.

`clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(clqueue, res_nb_g, &res_nb, 0, NULL, NULL);`

This line likely fails with `CL_INVALID_VALUE`, because `&res_nb` is not
an original pointer. It is just a pointer to a local variable not known to to
the OpenCL runtime.

`res_nb = *((cl_uint *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(clqueue, res_nb_g, CL_TRUE, [...]);`

This line has the same issues as well, but it also does not have a corresponding
`clEnqueueUnmapMemObject`. Even though the buffer is mapped for Read, you still
have to call `clEnqueueUnmapMemObject` to let the runtime 'free' this mapped
memory.

See [clEnqueueMapBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMapBuffer.html) and [clEnqueueUnmapMemObject](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueUnmapMemObject.html) in the OpenCL
specification for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I update with my solution.
Is this the correct direction to go / more efficient way?

Comment: You still have to unmap the last clEnqueueMapBuffer, but yes, this should work fine. In addition, if you use in-order command queue, you don't need clFinish between clEnqueueNDRangeKernel and clEnqueueMapBuffer, because the latter one is blocking.

Comment: OK. Is more efficient way than `clEnqueueWriteBuffer/clEnqueueReadBuffer` ?

Comment: In general I'd say yes, but you can always make a benchmark to check which way is better for your use case.